# iAd not call full screen ads

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iad

I have implemented full screen ads using iAds, But unfortunately it was not working see below code.

```
-(void)showFullScreenAd {
    if (_requestingAd == NO) {
        _interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
        _interstitial.delegate = self;
        NSLog(@"Ad Request");
        _requestingAd = YES;
    }

}

-(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    _requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"Ad didFailWithERROR");
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

-(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    NSLog(@"Ad DidLOAD");
    if (interstitialAd.loaded) {

        CGRect interstitialFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)-90);
        interstitialFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 44);
        _adView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:interstitialFrame];
        [self.view addSubview:_adView];

        [_interstitial presentInView:_adView];

        UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(closeAd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
        [_adView addSubview:button];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [_adView setAlpha:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

-(void)closeAd:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [_adView setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    _adView=nil;
    _requestingAd = NO;
}

-(void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    _requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"Ad DidUNLOAD");
}

-(void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    _requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"Ad DidFINISH");
}
```

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you in an iAd supported country?

Comment: What minimum iOS version require ? In my case I have support 6.0 as well

Comment: I would suspect iOS 7.0 is the minimum for implementing an `ADInterstitialAd` on an iPhone. Interstitials for iPhone were introduced in September of 2013, [UIViewController iAd Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013388), when iOS 7 was released. Do you receive an interstitial when testing on iOS 7.0 and greater?

Comment: But banner view also doesn't work. I got error in IOS 9 ...Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown error" UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=102, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unknown error, ADInternalErrorDomain=WebKitErrorDomain}

Comment: It may just be an issue with iAd delivering advertisements to your region at the moment then. You should [contact Apple](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs).

Comment: Okay Thanks, what Xcode version you used ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I was thinking maybe my account is not active yet for iAds. Were you able to fix this??

Comment: full screen ad not working in ios9 and ios8 . banner  add doesn't shown on ios9 but working on ios8. plz update if u got any solution @MDSingh

Comment: @DipenChudasama Did you got any solutions for this in iOS9?

Comment: Not sure, B'coz Not tested yet